# How do nest objects and share variables using prototype having multiple sub-prototype objects?

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript and I am trying to understand how inheritance works, I have used C++ before and is pretty easy handle variables from main classes to their descendants, I have trying prototype method but doesn't work that easy.
Here are my codes... What is the right way to do it???

```js
function main() {
  this.name = "main object, name";

}
main.prototype.LevelA1 = function() {
  return "LevelA1 method " + this.name; //this level read this.name right
}
main.prototype.LevelA = function() {
  this.a = "laaaa"
  return "LevelA " + this.name; //variable this.name is visible

}

main.prototype.LevelA.LevelB = function() {

  return this.name + " Level B " + this.a //this.name undefined
}
main.prototype.LevelA.LevelB.LevelC = function() {
  return "level C" + this.name; //this.name not visible and not produce error
}
main.prototype.LevelA.LevelB.LevelC.LevelD = function() {
  this.bb = "variable of levelD"
  return "Level D " + this.bb + this.name; //this.name not visible and ot produce error

}
m = new main();
console.log(m.LevelA());
console.log(m.LevelA.LevelB());
console.log(m.LevelA.LevelB.LevelC());
console.log(m.LevelA.LevelB.LevelC.LevelD());
var cc = new m.LevelA.LevelB.LevelC.LevelD();
console.log(cc.bb);
```

Comment: I don't think it has any bearing on the question or answers, but please note that I've replaced your `alert`s with `log`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting new functions rather than setting new prototypes, so the lexical context for every new function is nothing to do with `Main.prototype`.

I recommend you to approach your logic using classes.

*This approach wraps the "Level" functions inside of a class which extends from `Main` class.*

```js
class Main {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "main object, name";
  }
}

class MainLevel extends Main {
  LevelA1() {
    return "LevelA1 method " + this.name; //this level read this.name right  
  }

  LevelA() {
    this.a = "laaaa"
    return "LevelA " + this.name; //variable this.name is visible
  }

  LevelB() {
    return this.name + " Level B " + this.a //this.name undefined
  }

  LevelC() {
    return "level C" + this.name; //this.name not visible and not produce error
  }

  LevelD() {
    this.bb = "variable of levelD"
    return "Level D " + this.bb + this.name; //this.name not visible and ot produce error

  }
}

let m = new MainLevel();
console.log(m.LevelA());
console.log(m.LevelB());
console.log(m.LevelC());
console.log(m.LevelD());
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, it has solved this particular problem, but what I really need is to know how to make like a 'TREE' where a main object can have multiple objects and these objects sub-objects and so on... and "all the children inherits the properties of their ancestors". (*with variables that are not global so they can not interferes with any script that can uses this object). how can it be achieved in JavaScript?